# Query the list of all the languages used in a postgresql DB column

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

I have a column that can contain any language.  Is it possible to get a list of all the languages that are represented in that column.  For example, if my column contained the following rows:

- Hello, how are you?
- こんにちは、元気ですか？
- Salut comment allez-vous?

I would expect my query to return English, Japanese, and French (or some reasonable indication of what the language is).

Things to note:

- My database is UTF8.
- A single cell will normally only contain 1 language but it is possible to be mixed.
- It's preferable that the solution use native postgresql tools.

Comment: Can you define " some reasonable indication of what the language is"

Comment: Sure.  I don't specifically care if the results say "English" or "Japanese" as long as I have some way to tell what they are.  If the query returned something like en-us or some other identifier that I could map to a language that would be sufficient.  My reason in adding that was I didn't want people to get hung up on formatting of the results as long as I was able to determine what the language is.

Comment: You will almost certainly need some kind of AI for that job since the problem is quite complex. As an exemple french and english share a lot of words and since they might be mixed there is no efficient way to know which one it is in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, most database management systems, including PostgreSQL, are only aware of *character sets*, not languages. Since many languages share characters and very few contain characters unique to themselves, it is impractical, if not impossible, to attempt to determine a language with any degree of accuracy by checking for the presence of specific characters.

The real challenge of your question lies in the exclusive use of native PostgreSQL tools. PostgreSQL supports [extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/external-extensions.html).

> PostgreSQL is designed to be easily extensible. For this reason, extensions loaded into the database can function just like features that are built in.

However, I have thus far been unable to find one that deals with human language. It may be possible to leverage the PostgreSQL extension framework to write your own.

If you are truly desperate to attempt a PostgreSQL-native solution, I suppose you could attempt to implement a language detection algorithm in a [user-defined function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc.html). The description of how to go about such a task is beyond the scope of this answer.

My first inclination, however, is to set up an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) (extract, transform, load) pipeline that works over your language fields, determines their language, and writes to a separate series of tables that will act like an index. Every time the ETL system detects a language not yet seen, it adds it to a languages table which has a unique constraint on the language name and/or an [ISO 639 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). A many-to-many relationship table would then relate your source language records to your detected language code records.

I would probably attempt to use a third-party library available for your language of choice (example:
 [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect) for Python) or a third-party service such as the [Google Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/). The documentation details the painless use of the [language detection feature](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language):

> You can detect the language of a text string by sending an HTTP request using a URL of the following format: `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect`

For a third-party service, you may need a paid account depending upon the volume of your data. Batch API requests would be beneficial. For both libraries and services, I would also try to determine the average accuracy that can be expected for the results by reading documentation, looking for user reports and reviews, and running my own empirical tests.

Comment: The constraint to do it in the database was primarily because of the amount of data.  Third party solutions may work but I was hoping for something easy in the DB.  I would even be fine with an "in the ballpark" estimate of what the language was.

Comment: @brainimus I am 97.8% certain that it would be far faster to perform language detection outside of PostgreSQL. Database management engines  are very focused pieces of software and one of the things on which they do _not_ focus is logic that is any more complex than basic comparisons, string manipulations, and arithmetic. That said, I edited my answer to include the possibility of implementing a simple language detection algorithm in a user-defined function.